# Casting wire vector to integer in verilog

Tags: verilog

In an example like this

```verilog
function module(
    input [3:0] in
    output out); 
    for(integer i = in; i < in+10; i += 1) begin
        // do stuff
    end
endfunction
```

How would `in` be cast to `i`?
From what I understand an integer is a 32-bit bit vector, interpreted in 2's complement.
So does verilog pad the bit vector with `28{in[3]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From LRM

> If needed, extend the size of the right-hand side, performing sign extension if, and only if, the type of the right-hand side is signed.

So, in your case `i` will be padded with '0', not with *in[3]*, because `in` is not signed.

To do sign extension, you will need to make in signed: `input signed [3:0] in;`